# ExtJS 6 Ext.field.Date doesnt contain header of Ext.panel.Date

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

I need a simple way to select year with `Ext.field.Date` component.

`Ext.panel.Date` contains header with ability to select year. However, `Ext.field.Date`, which internally use `Ext.panel.Date`, doesn't contain this header.

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2vf9) to illustrate what I mean.

How I can show this header in `Ext.field.Date` picker? Maybe I missed some config or so? Or its a bug and I have to fix it in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it happens because the header in the calendar is empty object `Ext.panel.Date`

```
override: 'Ext.panel.Date',
constructor: function(config){
    delete config.header
    this.callParent([config])
},
```